# Sitecore TreelistEx used as a UI for multi-link layouts

Tags: sitecore

I need to present a content editor interface that allows editors to select specific pages in order to generate a link list for website visitors.

It seems treelist/treelistEX is providing the expected interface and I have combined that with a source path to lock the editors to a start destination rather than the entire sitecore tree. Opted for treelist EX as this appears to be the most efficient way as it doesnt render the tree in full each time unless its called upon.

In terms of the output however I'm getting a pipe separated list of GUIDs- is this something I need to iterate through manually using linkmanager or some such to obtain the items title and its sitecore link? Or is there an existing process that manages such a multi-list and breaks it up into its components.

If anyone can provide an example of that code and how to draw out the title and URL that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in solution for getting title and url from the items selected in `Treelist`.

You can treat your `Treelist` field as a `Multilist` field (they both store just list of pipe separated IDs in the background) and use `GetItems()` method:

```cs
Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField treelistField = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["myTreelistFieldName"]; 
Item [] selectedItems = treelistField.GetItems();

foreach (Item item in selectedItems)
{
    string itemName = item.Name;
    string displayName = item.DisplayName; // fallback to Name if not set
    string title = item["Title"]; // assuming there is a field called Title
    string url = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item);
}
```

Comment: Hi Marek thank you for a quick reply. I am fairly new to Sitecore so please forgive me if this is a basic query but once GetItems is used how would I iterate through each Item and obtain its values? Thanks again

Comment: Thank you very much for further explanation: sadly I get an exception error using the above code which I believe is down to the getItems line. I have wrapped it in a check for !null and it seems to hit that check and believe it is null however writing out Item.Fields["Link Location"].Value does generate an output do these is content but it seems to fall over thinking the item is null. should i be pointing to Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField treelistField = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Link Location"].value perhaps?

Comment: Is field `Link Location` on your page template? Or on datasource of your component? If the latter, you need to get datasource item first and then use `datasourceItem.Fields["Link Location"]`. Definitely you don't want to cast `.Value` to `Field`.

Comment: HI, the field is on the template for the sublayouts datasource - thank you for your suggestion I will amend  my code.

Comment: HI, so to obtain the datasource first something like:
var datasourceItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(this.DataSource);

            Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField treelistField = datasourceItem.Fields["Link Location"];

Comment: it depends on what is "this", if you use MVC or WebForms, etc. Google "Sitecore get datasource item mvc/webforms"